# Unittesting the SpeechRecognition API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, webkit, speech-recognition

The [webkitSpeechRecognition](http://apprentice.craic.com/tutorials/37) api is very much a blackbox to unit test

It looks like I have to speak into the browser if I want to test the api. Is anyone aware of alternate ways of testing a workflow which uses this api?

Comment: you could play back recorded files, but why would you want to unit test something you can't control anyway?

Comment: Speech recognition has a lag which I want to mask with other stuff. I do not want interim results. While I develop this part, it would be great if I don't have to speak to the computer every time.

Answer (score 1):

Try [corti](https://github.com/TalAter/corti) which replaces the browser's SpeechRecognition object with a mock object. This object replicated (most) of the native functionality, and adds some other helper methods to it to ease testing (e.g. a `say()` method 
to emulate speech input).

Here is some sample code with Corti:

```
// Patch the current environment with a mock Speech Recognition object
Corti.patch();

// Interact with the mock object, like with the real SpeechRecognition object
var recognition = new window.SpeechRecognition();
recognition.onstart = function() {console.log("I'm listening");};
recognition.addEventListener('result', function(sre) {
  console.log(sre.results.item(sre.resultIndex).item(0).transcript);
});
recognition.addEventListener('end', function() {console.log("Quiet");});
recognition.continuous = true;

// Use extra utility methods added to the mock object to assist with testing
expect(recognition.isStarted()).toBe(false);
recognition.start();
expect(recognition.isStarted()).toBe(true);
recognition.abort();
expect(recognition.isStarted()).toBe(false);

// Simulate speech recognition
recognition.addEventListener('result', mySpyFunction);
expect(mySpyFunction).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
recognition.say("Next time you want to stab me in the back, have the guts to do it to my face");
expect(mySpyFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
```